# Sending Array with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$('[data-toggle="mftapproveCheck"]').click(function () {


    var selected = $("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function (i, el) { return el.value; }).get();
   //alert("selected = [" + selected + "]\nas int = \"" + selected.join(";") + "\"");

    var url = $(this).data("url") + "/" + selected;
    var title = $(this).data("title");


        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $("#preLoader").fadeIn('fast');
                $.post(url, function (json) {
                    if (json.IsComplete) {
                        $("#" + id).remove();
                        BSToastr.show("success", "Başarılı", "İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirildi.");
                    }
                    else {
                        BSToastr.show("error", "Hata", "İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi.");
                    }
                    $("#preLoader").fadeOut('fast');
                });
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Here I am trying to send `selected` to controller. this works when only 1 Id comes but doesnt work when several comes. but alert always working. How can I send Array from here ?

```
public ActionResult ApproveSelected(int[] selected)
    {
        var itema = selected;
        var itemb = itema;
        try
        {

            var AllParticipants = Db.Participants
            .Where(m => selected.Contains(m.Id))
            .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
            .ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < AllParticipants.Count; i++)
            {

                var item = AllParticipants.First();
                item.Approval = true;

                var itemRemove = AllParticipants.First();
                AllParticipants.Remove(item);

            }

            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { IsComplete = false });
        }

        return Json(new { IsComplete = true });
    }
```

Comment: Please do not accept answers which are wrong and have nothing to do with your issue - it just misleads other users. To post back an array, use the `$.ajax()` method with `data: selected` and `traditional: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending a list because of this line:

```
var url = $(this).data("url") + "/" + selected;
```

which just concats `selected` without actually converting it. If you take a look at your `alert`, you actually convert it to a string via the `join` function which is why you see all the items.

```
selected.join(";"); // <-- used in your alert()
```

So what I'd suggest is using that same `join` call when setting your `url` variable:

```
var url = $(this).data("url") + "/" + selected.join(";");
```

Comment: still null with more than 1 numbers

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What is it that's null? Maybe give some sample values to help clarify your problem.

Comment: I get selected Ids from checkbox. And send it to controller.when I check 1 checkbox I can see Id in controller with breakpoints and also in alert when I check a few checkboxes I see null in controller and I can see Ids in alert. Will add my controller

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your routes configuration not parameterizing the list for you to reference in your controller, which is a different issue. I recommend you marking this question as answered for your original issue with javascript and posting a new question for your server side routes issue.

Comment: I think the problem is with this part here ? $.post(url, function (json) {